# Making a Button class(no use of swing)

Tags: java, jcomponent

First, the code below works as intended(except for the part I have not been able to test for reasons I will state below)

```
  public class Button implements MouseListener {

  String function;
  int currentState;
  int[] pos;
  int[] size;
  private BufferedImage normal;
  private BufferedImage hover;
  private BufferedImage click;
  BufferedImage currentImage;

  public Button(String func, String location, int[] position,int[] dimensions){
  function = func;
  //State 0 means not interacted with, State 1 means hovered and state 2 means clicked
  currentState = 0;
  pos = position;
  size = dimensions;

  String dpath = "/Images/";
  String npath = dpath+location+".png";
  String hpath = dpath+location+"h.png";
  String cpath = dpath+location+"c.png";
  try{
  normal =ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(npath));
  hover =ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(hpath));
  click =ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(cpath));
  }catch(Exception e){
  System.err.println("Error loading button image: "+ e);
  } 
  currentImage = normal;
  }

  private void changeState(int c){
  currentState = c;
  changeImage();
  }
  private void changeImage(){
  if (currentState == 0){
  currentImage = normal;
  }else if (currentState == 1){
  currentImage = hover;
  }else if (currentState == 2){
  currentImage = click;
  }

  public int getX(){
  return pos[0];
  }
  public int getY(){
  return pos[1];
  }
  public BufferedImage getSprite(){
  return currentImage;
  }
```

This is painted onto the screen from a different class using

```
  g.drawImage(but.getSprite(), but.getX(), but.getY(), null);
```

I have it set so when the button is clicked hovered and left alone the button will use changeState() and changeImage().

In each of my methods (mousePressed,mouseReleased,mouseEntered and mouseExited) I have set the parameters for these to change the image but for obvious reasons none of these will be activated unless I have defined an area and to what I have read , the area that the MouseListener can well listen into are any JComponents. Does this mean that I need to use a JLabel (due to its mostly interactive nature by default) or is there a better way to implement a clickable area?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) after that I will give you a simple class to see how to draw image on JPanel or JComponent then u can try working on with mouseMotion :

***Example drawing image on*** "JPanel" :

```
`import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawOnJ extends JPanel{

    BufferedImage MyImage;

    public ImagePanel() {
       try {                
          MyImage = ImageIO.read(new File("your img path/name"));
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        gr.drawImage(MyImage, 0, 0, this); 
    }

}`
```

***And this for drawing image on*** "JLabel" :

```
BufferedImage image = null; // get your buffered image.
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon((Image)image);
JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setIcon(icon);
```